# ios UIPasteboard equivalent on flutter

Tags: flutter, clipboard, uipasteboard

How can i access the pasteboard of iOS using Flutter? I can manipulate only text with `Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: 'mycontent'));`, but i need send data to my clipboard. Some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Clipboard
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/Clipboard-class.html

exam:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
...

RaisedButton(
  child: Text('copy'),
  onPressed: () {
    Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: 'mycontent'));
  },
),
```